# Looking for a good semantic parser for the Russian language

Tags: prolog, nlp, semantic-analysis, parse-tree

Does anyone know of a semantic parser for the Russian language? I've attempted to configure the link-parser available from [link-grammar site](http://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/) but to no avail.

I'm hoping for a system that can run on the Mac and generate either a prolog or lisp-like representation of the parse tree (but XML output is fine as well).

Answer (score 1):

Try the first demo from http://semanticanalyzer.info/blog/demo/

The parser is not an opensource/free project, but we might figure out ways of collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

Also try looking at the NLTK library. It is multi lingual and even comes with a corpus with different languages. It uses Python though, but the output should be easy to write in a LISPy format.

other advantages include open source, and it is covered by a good O'Reilly book which is also available for free download - a sort of open source book.